# Connecting to Apache web Server in Auto Scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver, autoscaling, aws-application-load-balancer

Deploying Apache web Server via AWS - Which EC2 instance should I connect to after creating Auto-Scaling group?

I am trying to install Apache Web server in Multi Availability. I need to test the server by implementing a simple html file and having it display as a webpage. This is my first time using more than one EC2 instance for an application, and I am an AWS Console/CLI beginner.

I have created a security group, an autoscaling group that has created 2 EC2 instances, and an ALB. I also created a new key pair for CLI use.
I am also configuring a Record Set to access the html page using a link.

I know how to use the `ssh ec2-user@` command to configure the web sever using one EC2 instance, but  have two instances in my case. I have no idea how to ssh to the EC2 instances (is there a way to connect to both EC2 instances, or to the autoscaling group)? How does it work for multiple EC2 instances accessing the same html code?

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for answering programming questions. You might get a better response from sites like [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: You have way too many questions! Let's start with getting SSH working for you. Would you know whether your EC2 instances are in a public subnet? How is the Security Group configured for your instances? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you, and sorry for the multiple questions. I figured out how to fix this issue on my own after some trial and error. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: In that case, feel free to delete this question if it does not contain anything useful for future readers.